# Bug with sharing via SLComposerSheet

Tags: xcode, facebook, slcomposeviewcontroller

So i use SLComposerSheet in my project for share text and image into Facebook. Today 27 April after update facebook application i have interesting problem, method setInitialText doesn't work!. I determined that if i deleted fecebook app from iPhone, method setInitialText works perfectly! Maybe someone know how to fix this bug? Or we must to wait update for Xcode?[image]

Comment: It's by design. According to Facebook Platform Policy, you can't pre-fill using iOS share sheet. See more here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill. Relevant discussion: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/962985360399542/

Comment: Wow thanks dude for found this post. Really its very good - We have a fix for this issue and it should be resolved in the next version of the Facebook iOS App.